# How to jump a line with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to add text to a div by using css code (and not directly in the html page). I want to add a sentence in a div (class = title) but I want to jump a line in this sentence at some point.

My css is:

```
.title
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.title: after
{  
  content: "Part 1 Part 2";
  visibility: visible;
  margin-left: -220px;
}
```

I would like to jump a line between Part 1 and Part 2.
I thought maybe it worked by using something like `\n` or `\a` but it didn't work.

Thank you,

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/z0eyaxgn/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
.title {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.title:after {
  content: "Part 1 \A Part 2";
  visibility: visible;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"></div>
```

Comment: I tried already but i have that displayed: Part 1<br>Part 2